# Mediawiki purge as a user right

Tags: mediawiki

Using Mediawiki 1.34.1, PHP 7.4.5, and MySQL 8.0.20.

I'd like for any user to be able to purge a page without confirmation.

Reading here it says I can do so by setting a user right:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Purge#Purge_as_a_user_right

And here it lists 'purge' as the specific user right: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights

And in MediaWiki's DefaultSettings.php it even has the following setting for it:

$wgGroupPermissions['user' ]['purge'] = true; // can use ?action=purge without clicking "ok"

However it continually prompts for confirmation, even when logged in.

I've added the same permission statement to LocalSettings.php, but the behavior didn't change.

Does this user right still work?

Or more to the point, how can I avoid the confirmation of the purge?

I've asked at the Mediawiki Support Desk, but haven't gotten any definitive answers, so I was wondering if anyone here might know, or know where I might check in the code to see if that specific user right is still effective.

Comment: `?action=purge` was converted from an automatic action to a form as part of the general effort of ensuring GET requests do not have side effects (besides HTTP standards compliance, it is important for multi-datacenter support). I'm not sure if the permission is used for anything today.

Comment: Thanks, @Tgr, as far as I can see in the code it doesn't.